# in Android why we have - Context.getSharedPreferences() and -Activity.getPreferences()?

Tags: android

in Android why we have
- Context.getSharedPreferences()
 and 
-Activity.getPreferences()
but we can change the model in each one between private and multiple so it will be same !! i know there is another function but what is it ?

Answer (score 1):

Always useful to read the documentation first! Furthermore reading the source code **really** helps a lot at times.

1. [Context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int))
   This is the main method. What it does is it fetches the contents of preference file "**name**", stores and returns it via a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
2. [Activity.getPreferences(int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int))
   As said, this just calls the above, but with specific name which actually is equal to:
   `getLocalClassName()`
3. [PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context))
   This also calls *Number 1* with the name: `getPackageName() + "_preferences";`

That said you can also supply the first two methods with ones of these modes:

- [MODE_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE)
  The default mode you should be using (also default for *Number 3*).
- [MODE_MULTI_PROCESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)
  Meant to be used if your application has multiple processes, where a singleton is not enough to keep the preferences up-to-date.
- <strike>MODE_WORLD_READABLE</strike> Deprecated in API 17
- <strike>MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE</strike> Deprecated in API 17